# Insert new li alphabetically by content of two children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fairly long list (~ 500 elements), that's sorted alphabetically, first by `title` and then by `subtitle`.

It looks something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="title>Alfred</span>
    <span class="subtitle>23</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="title>Ben</span>
    <span class="subtitle>25</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="title>Bruce</span>
    <span class="subtitle>27</span>
  </li>
  <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Now I have to insert a new element at the right position. What's the best way to accomplish this with jQuery? Thanks! :)

```
<!-- New element -->
<li>
  <span class="title>John</span>
  <span class="subtitle>24</span>
</li>
```

Comment: insertBefore/insertAfter

Comment: I see no effort on your part. What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Yes, insertBefore/insertAfter. The question is about finding the right position. That's where I'm out of ideas

Comment: "What's the best way" = vote to close as opinion based.  Perhaps you meant "how can I accomplish this"?

Comment: Where are your ~500 elements coming from and what format are they in? My first thought is get them into an array and use jQuery's `.sort()` method.

Comment: I'd go with something like `$("li>span.title").map(function() { return $(this).text() < obj.title; }).last().insertAfter("<li...` - but what have *you* tried?

Comment: Or you can treat the whole DOM as storage and use selectors to `.each` through all your `<li></li>'s` looking for the correct place alphabetically to insert a new entry. See the comment from @freedomn-m for additional info...

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with them after - similar to @Dan 's idea - if you need it stored then send to the back-end and get a new sorted list back.  (probably a bit pants without paging on 500+ records)

Answer (score 1):

Set your new element to a variable.

```
var newLi = $(`<li>
  <span class="title>John</span>
  <span class="subtitle>24</span>
</li>`);
```

Get an array of `li` elements.

```
var li = $("ul li");
```

Then loop through all of them and compare `span`s alphabetically. Add new `li` in correct position.

```
// Fallback just in case this name is alphabetically last
var delta = li.length;

li.each(function() {
  --delta;

  if($(this).find("span:first-child").text() < newLi.find("span:first-child").text()) {
    // Insert new element
    $(this).after(newLi);

    // Break from loop
    return false;
  }
});

if(delta == 0) $(li.last()).after(newLi)
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9bzc7j6v/)

Comment: this code will sort by title only. Also I added this code to jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6gv8ha1w/ and it's not working as expected.

Comment: @Digvijay given the lack of effort in the original question, I would leave it to OP to extend to also sort by subtitle.  SO is not a code writing service.